# How to compare two lists in python?

Tags: python, list

How to compare two lists in python?

```
date = "Thu Sep 16 13:14:15 CDT 2010" 
sdate = "Thu Sep 16 14:14:15 CDT 2010" 
dateArr = [] dateArr = date.split() 
sdateArr = [] sdateArr = sdate.split()
```

Now I want to compare these two lists. I guess split returns a list. We can do simple comparision in Java like `dateArr[i] == sdateArr[i]`, but how can we do it in Python?

Comment: By the way, you might find the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) type handy if you want to work with times rather than generic lists of strings.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You could always do just:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=['a','b']
c=[1,2,3,4]
d=[1,2,3]

a==b    #returns False
a==c    #returns False
a==d    #returns True
```

Answer (score 39):

```
a = ['a1','b2','c3']
b = ['a1','b2','c3']
c = ['b2','a1','c3']

# if you care about order
a == b # True
a == c # False

# if you don't care about order AND duplicates
set(a) == set(b) # True
set(a) == set(c) # True
```

By casting `a`, `b` and `c` as a set, you remove duplicates and order doesn't count. Comparing sets is also much faster and more efficient than comparing lists.

Comment: Its incorrect to turn arrays into sets - it will throw duplicated items, not only remove order. Try to compare arrays [1,2] and [1, 1, 2, 2, 2] with sets.

Comment: @DenisBarmenkov I don't see the problem. Can you point out the problem? Python repl: `>>> set([1,2]) == set([1,1,2,2,2])` produces `True`

Comment: Sets contain unique numbers but lists have an order. [1,2] does not equal to [2,1]. Or we have to change topic question. Also you could take a look on likes count :/

Answer (score 5):

If you mean lists, try `==`:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]

l1 == l2 # False
```

If you mean [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html):

```
l1 = array('l', [1, 2, 3])
l2 = array('d', [1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
l1 == l2 # True
l2 = array('d', [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
l1 == l2 # False
```

If you want to compare strings (per your comment):

```
date_string  = u'Thu Sep 16 13:14:15 CDT 2010'
date_string2 = u'Thu Sep 16 14:14:15 CDT 2010'
date_string == date_string2 # False
```

Comment: dateArray = Thu Sep 16 13:14:15 CDT 2010

Comment: @Umesh - how is that an array?

Comment: sdateArray = Thu Sep 16 14:14:15 CDT 2010

Comment: Now both these dates were string I created array out of that but how do I compare them using for loop?

Comment: @Umesh - post the code where you created the two strings, otherwise all of us are just guessing at what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Umesh: this information belongs in the body of the question, not comments.

Comment: I know it looks like string you can understand them as arrays.

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble actually I am using StackOverflow for the first time so not familiar with UI.

Comment: date= "Thu Sep 16 13:14:15 CDT 2010"

Comment: date = "Thu Sep 16 13:14:15 CDT 2010"
sdate = "Thu Sep 16 14:14:15 CDT 2010"

dateArr = []
dateArr = date.split()
sdateArr = []
sdateArr = sdate.split()

Now I want to compare these two array I guess split returns array. We can do simple comparision in Jav
like dateArr[i] == sdateArr[i] but how can we do it in Java?

Sorry for trouble Please help

Comment: @Umesh Kacha: Scroll up and look at your question. Below it there are several buttons. The second from the left says `edit`. This can be used to edit your question, for instance if you want to add additional information.

Answer (score 4):

Given the code you provided in comments, I assume you want to do this:

```
>>> dateList = "Thu Sep 16 13:14:15 CDT 2010".split()
>>> sdateList = "Thu Sep 16 14:14:15 CDT 2010".split()
>>> dateList == sdataList
false
```

The `split`-method of the string returns a list. A list in Python is very different from an array. `==` in this case does an element-wise comparison of the two lists and returns if all their elements are equal and the number and order of the elements is the same. Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in arr1:
    if i in arr2:
        return 1
    return  0
arr1=[1,2,5]
arr2=[2,4,15]
q=checkarrayequalornot(arr1,arr2)
print(q)
>>0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Answer (score 0):

From your post I gather that you want to compare dates, not arrays. If this is the case, then use the appropriate object: a `datetime` object.

Please check the documentation for the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html). Dates are a tough cookie. Use reliable algorithms.